# functional assembly language

Tags: assembly, functional-programming, cpu-architecture

Lets say there was an architecture XYZ which was optimised for functional languages (like haskell). Can any tell me the advantages of such an architecture and also a "functional" assembly language?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lazily evaluated RAM? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

forth is lightweight and low-level lisp.. and,

[stack-computer architecture](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack_computers/) for forth and lisp

[lisp-machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine)

[Second-Generation Stack Computer Architecture](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:K6TYK9KdKiMJ:is.uwaterloo.ca/Eric_LaForest_Thesis.pdf+stack+computer&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShvHg6_cwmRBuIr7lce3iYYsFMX919d7C3fcG48JyjUqkLpgtFEuf9sdU2NCzmK-2Mn0r4gS1JeENtMJA8uGw38UnQxfeU9Rb2l_za1klAit_vCkkRZ7eDuq5p-bUaTTL4xuddO&sig=AHIEtbQpF5Ih3P2HvZ17r43pxvs150HSLg) ([pdf](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/10810/LaForest_Eric.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)) ([scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Second-Generation+Stack+Computer+Architecture&btnG=))

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible since any real hardware is imperative, by its nature. It's like a trinary machine - it's good in theory, but you can't realize it in hardware.

Comment: But wait ... the "Second-Generation Stack Computer Architecture" by LaForest posted by plan9assembler seems to indicate that a functional architecture /is/ possible at the hardware level.

Comment: You can do anything in hardware -- if it's not done simply means it's easier/cheaper to do it in software.